# How to set IBM MQ GET Read ahead MaximumSize in java

Tags: java, performance, ibm-mq

I want to increase IBM MQ MQGET throughput and notice in some conditions I can use QueueManager MQOO_READ_AHEAD option. In this way after first get execution, many records are transferred from server to client lib and be ready to read on next GETs. I want to control size of this read ahead messages count. I noticed that there is some Configuration properties as MaximumSize, PurgeTime, and UpdatePercentage but how can I set/control these values in my java client code?

Comment: Tarvirdi: And in the other hand, when closing connection, Buffered data is lost.

Answer (score 2):

The properties that control behaviour of the client side ReadAhead message buffer are set with the client configuration file, mq client.ini under the MessageBuffer stanza:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016890_.htm

Here is a link to the documentation that describes the client configuration file and the locations on the system where the MQ Java client code attempts to load it from:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016840_.htm

I'm not aware of way to specify the MaximumSize, PurgeTime and UpdatePercentage properties programmatically within an application.

**Update:**
You can set the three MessageBuffer properties as Java system properties using the names:

```
com.ibm.mq.cfg.MessageBuffer.MaximumSize

com.ibm.mq.cfg.MessageBuffer.PurgeTime

com.ibm.mq.cfg.MessageBuffer.UpdatePercentage
```

Therefore you could set these using -D flags on the Java command when the application is invoked or via `System.setProperty(String, String)` calls within the application code itself - so long as the properties are set before any MQ classes for JMS/classes for Java API calls are made.